# Nested React Native ScrollView requires two taps to start scrolling

Tags: android, ios, react-native, scrollview

I have a `ScrollView` inside another `ScrollView`. I noticed that I have to tap twice in order to make the nested scroll view start scrolling.

I tried using some properties like `scrollEnabled`, `nestedScrollEnabled` and `keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always"` but none of these helped.

I can't provide any real code because the project is quite big and there are multiple components in between the scroll views. However, the basic structure is similar to this:

```
<ScrollView>
  <SomeNestedComponents>
    <ScrollView
      scrollEnabled={true}
      nestedScrollEnabled={true}
      keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always"
    >
    </ScrollView>
  </SomeNestedComponents>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you try putting `keyboardShouldPersistTaps='always'` on the outermost `<ScrollView />` component as well. According to the final answer in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10138#issuecomment-406075420), that should fix it.

For example:

```
<ScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps='always'>
  <SomeNestedComponents>
    <ScrollView
      scrollEnabled={true}
      nestedScrollEnabled={true}
      keyboardShouldPersistTaps='always'
    >
    </ScrollView>
  </SomeNestedComponents>
</ScrollView>
```